# jquery visible select box change event

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to know why the below code is not working as expected.

```
/***** selecting select box having options 5,6 *****/
$("select:visible:first").change(function () {
 alert("hi");
});
```

for structure like

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
 </select>

 <select>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div>
 <select>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
 </select>

 <select>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

The idea is that when somebody clicks on first of two, select boxes which are visible, I should show the selected value. But somehow the change() is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('select').is(':hidden')) {
   put here what you wanna change...
}
```

I'll give you a little start up :)

comment if your not geting a hold with it :)

Comment: Hi, I am not quite getting it. I will need an onchange event on select box. so I will need an object to hold on to. e.g. $("select").change() ... the above if will just check for true-false. I am not sure, but I might be missing on something too.

Comment: Not sure if there is any proper answer. For sake of closing this question. Here is what I did.

`<select onchange='callMe();' >
 <option>5</option>
 <option>6</option>
 </select>
`

In callMe(),
`function callMe()
{
  alert($("select:visible:first option:selected"));
}
`

If there are any better answers, then please do post it here.

Answer (score 0):

the listener is getting attached for third select box ie. the select box with values 5,6
http://jsfiddle.net/eLxvr/ 
this behaviour is correct as:

The first 2 select boxes are in a div with style `display:none` therefore `$("select:visible:first")` will return the third select box as it is the first visible one.

Comment: true. I checked it in firebug console [test jquery using firebug](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) too. Somehow it should work. but when i do $("select:visible:first").change() it is not called at all. I even tried placing it under $(document).ready() but that didn't help too.

Comment: Not sure if there is any proper answer. For sake of closing this question. Here is what I did.

`<select onchange='callMe();' >
 <option>5</option>
 <option>6</option>
 </select>
`

In callMe(),
`function callMe()
{
  alert($("select:visible:first option:selected"));
}
`

If there are any better answers, then please do post it here.